# How do I send request in robot framework for api testing

Tags: api, post, request, robotframework

I am passing username and password in the Post request body but it gives Issue as  Client Error: “Not Acceptable for url: [https://apiexample.com/demo”](https://apiexample.com/demo%E2%80%9D)
#but when I use json file to pass username and password then it works but I don't want to pass json file instead I want to give my username and password in the request body

```
*** Variables ***
${base_Url}=    https://apiexample.com

*** Test Cases ***
GenerateToken
    ${headers}=  create dictionary   Content-Type=application/json
    ${body}=    create dictionary    username=abc@example.in   password=abc123
    #${body}=   get file  /Users/Documents/data.json   // (but i don't want to use this file method
    create session  mysession   ${base_Url}     headers=${headers}
    ${response}=    Post On Session    mysession   /demo  data=${body}   headers=${headers}

    log to console  ${response.status_code}
```

Comment: What is the difference between ${body} when you use create dictionary and get file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass request body in form of JSON format

```
*** Settings ***
Library           RequestsLibrary

*** Variables ***
&{JSON}    username=abc@example.in    password=abc123

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    create session  mysession   ${base_Url}     headers=${headers}
    ${response}=    Post On Session    mysession   /demo   json=${JSON}   headers=${headers} 
    Log    ${response}
```